# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on inserting

Tags: sqlite, insert, exc-bad-access, fmdb

I'm using FMDatabase to operate on an sqlite3 database. Here's my code:

```
NSString *dbFilePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"temp_info.db"]];

FMDatabase *fmdb = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:dbFilePath];
if (![fmdb open]) {
    NSLog(@"......");
} else {
    NSString *sql = @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test1(id INTEGER, name TEXT, create_time TEXT)";
    if (![fmdb executeUpdate:sql]) {
        NSLog(@"......");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        BOOL result = [fmdb executeUpdate:@"INSERT INTO test1(id, name, create_time) values(?,?,?)", i+1, @"test", @"12-09-10 12:10"];
        NSLog(@"%d", result);
    }
    // EXC_BAD_ACCESS
}
```

When I run the line:

```
BOOL result = [fmdb executeUpdate:@"INSERT INTO test1(id, name, create_time) values(?,?,?)", i+1, @"test", @"12-09-10 12:10"];
```

I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error. Why?

Comment: If you have solved the question you still need to accept your own answer. This will mark the question closed.

Answer (score 9):

question has been solved!
**1.**All arguments provided to the `-executeUpdate:` method(or any of the variants that accept a `va_list` as a parameter) must be objects.The following will be not work (and will result in a crash):
`[db executeUpdate:@"INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (?)", 66];`
The proper way to insert a number is to box it in an `NSNumber` object:
`[db executeUpdate:@"INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (?)", [NSNumber numberWithInt:66]];`
**2.**Alternatively,you can use the `-execute*WithFormat:` variant to use `NSString`-style substitution:
`[db executeUpdateWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (%d)", 66];`
Internally,the `-execute*WithFormat:` methods are properly boxing things for you.The following percent modifiers are recognized:
`%@`,`%c`,`%s`,`%d`,`%D`,`%i`,`%u`,`%U`,`%hi`,`%hu`,`%qi`,`%qu`,`%f`,`%ld`,`%lu`,`%lld`,and `%llu`.
Using a modifier other than those will have unpredictable results.If,for some reason,you need the `%` character to appear in your SQL statement,you should use `%%`.